# iPhone - GestureRecognizer sometimes doesn't fire?

Tags: iphone, ios, keypress, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to get a long key press on a button working in objective c for iPhone.

Here is the code I have put together for the GestureRecognizer:

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //1 second
    longPressGesture.delegate = self;
    [deleteButton addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [longPressGesture release];
```

And here is the function that I use in the selector to call when a long key press is detected.

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"Got handle long key press");
        NumLabel.text = @"";

    }

}
```

I have also added the following functions as part of my delegate class but they don't seem to have had any impact:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return NO;

}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

    return YES;

}
```

My issue is that this sometimes works but then again sometimes it doesn't, most of the time I get the call to handleLongPress and it works fine but every so often when the button is pressed and held down I get nothing until I lift my finger off the button at which stage my normal code for the button is run.

Have I missed something in the tutorials or can anyone spot why it would work sometimes but I get nothing on other occasions?

**EDIT**

I actually think the issue is with the way the button is pressed, if I press the button straight on and hold it then it works fine, however if my finger slips on the button even a little bit then the handleLongPress function isn't called.

I'm assuming this is because it recognizes it as a separate gesture? Is there a way to make sure that handleLongPress gets called as long as the button is held down even if the finger moves across the button at all?

Comment: Are you adding a gesture recognizer to a button?

Comment: UIControls (superclass of UIButton) already do a LOT of touch handling, I don't know for sure, but this might conflict with the touch handling of your gesture recognizer. Does it need to be a button? Can't it be a UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gesture recognizers are only for TOUCHES, not for button states. A Long press is really just pressing and releasing. When the touch moves, the gesture will be canceled!!

If you just want to know if your button is pressed more than a specific time, you can handle TouchDown/TouchCancel events of your button and add some timing.

Comment: Thanks, I had to use Touch Up Inside instead of Touch Cancel but its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can implement gesture recognizer along with the buttons.
here it goes:

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressButton:)];
    [someButtonName addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; 
    //longPress.delegate = self;
    [longPress release];`

use it where you are creating your button aur in the method where you want to implement it.and then

`- (void)longPressButton:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Long Pressed");
//your stuff here when detected long hold
    }
}`